# sql database,with multiple where, second max

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called [database] with the following structure:

```
ID|text|section|
1 |xxxx|   1   |
2 |xxxx|   2   |
3 |xxxx|   2   |
4 |xxxx|   1   |
5 |xxxx|   4   |
6 |xxxx|   1   |
```

I'm trying to write SQL which returns the row with the second highest ID value for a given section.

i.e. to get the row with the highest id value within section 1 I can do this:

```
select * 
from [database] 
where [ID] = 
(
    select max([ID])  
    from [database] 
    where [section] = 1
)
```

To get the row with the second highest ID value I tried this, but with the data below this returns the row with ID 5, whilst I'd expect it to return the row with ID 4.

```
select * 
from [database] 
where [ID]=
(
    select max([ID])-1  
    from [database] 
    where [section]=1
)
```

I was trying `AND` command but it doesn't work. 
I am newbie to SQL and ASP. 
I think for first I need filter on `section = 1` and then second maximum/highest `id` within this section; something like:

```
if( section == 1 && secMaximum )
{
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: What output do you get / what do you expect?  I think your code there would return the row with ID 3.

Comment: I have there more sections like 1-4 when i tried this code i got row with section number 3 and i wanted section 1..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...  Could you update your example to show a clear example of the data in your table vs what you're after; that may help illustrate your intention?

Comment: Here you go I hope you understand now.

Comment: Understood; thanks.  FYI: The ASP.Net bit you don't need to worry about adding an IF statement to; your SQL (i.e. either of the answers below) will give you what you're after / there won't be a need to filter it further outside of SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [Fubar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417775/361842) and [GordonLinoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417930/361842)'s answers are excellent and will work if you're using MySql.

In the comments you mentioned that you're using SQL Server (Management) Studio; which implies that you're using [Microsoft's SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) rather than [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/), as you had tagged in your question.  NB: These are different products, and whist the `SQL` language is similar for both, there are differences.

Here's a solution for MS Sql Server:

```
select [Id], [Text], [Section]
from 
(
    select *
    , Row_Number() over (partition by [Section] order by [Id] desc) MaxOrder
    from [Database]
    where [Section] = 1
) x
where MaxOrder = 2
```

You can try it out here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4dfce/2

Most of the SQL above you'll probably understand.
The confusing part is `Row_Number() over (partition by [Section] order by [Id] desc)`, so here's an explanation of that.

- `row_number()` is just an incremental number; i.e. the first row returned is 1, the second 2, and so on until the end of the "partition" (see next point).
- `partition by` creates the partitions; here we're partitioning by `Section`, so for the rows with `Section = 1`, `row_number()` returns 1, 2, 3, etc. then when for those rows with `Section = 2`, `row_number()` returns 1, 2, and so on.
- `order by` says how to decide how the numbering occurs within the partition; i.e. which row should get number 1, etc.  Here we're ordering by `Id desc`; i.e. the row with the highest `Id` in the `Section` is row 1, the second hightest row 2, etc.

If we only ran the statement below on your sample data we'd get the below results:

```sql
    select *
    , Row_Number() over (partition by [Section] order by [Id] desc) MaxOrder
    from [Database]
```

```
Id | Text | Section | MaxOrder
6  | xxxx |    1    |   1
4  | xxxx |    1    |   2
1  | xxxx |    1    |   3
3  | xxxx |    2    |   1
2  | xxxx |    2    |   2
5  | xxxx |    4    |   1
```

You can see that in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4dfce/3

The rest I think you'd understand; but please ask in the comments if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the second maximum, just use `offset`:

```
select a.*
from [database] a
where a.section = 1
order by a.id desc
limit 1, 1;
```

Comment: What the "a" Mean I have to do it in SQLquery so it's kinda diff. I need implement this code to ASP project

Comment: He is just using `a` as a placeholder for your table name... though he did forget **DESC** for the `ORDER BY`. ;)

Comment: Thanks but i cant use "limit" in Microsoft sql studio

Comment: I considered using `OFFSET` too, but it won't work if there's only one result for the given `section`.

Comment: @LukášKarpíšek . . . If you are using SQL Server Studio, then you are not using MySQL and the question is not properly tagged.  Perhaps you should ask *another* question with the proper tags and explanation of what to do in the case of ties.  This question already has answers and changing the question could invalidate them.

Answer (score 1):

If you select the two highest `id` values for the section, and then select the lowest of the two, you should get your desired result.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM [database] a 
  WHERE section = 1
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 2
) AS a1
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b413eb/3